# How make Query that returns all the rows of table of a specific date and all the related fields in the same row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: **blog** and **blog_translations**:

**blog**:

[image: Blog table]

---

**blog_translations**

[image: Blog Tranlations tabl]

---

**I have to perform a query that returns the following:**

[image: Result query]

That is to say: I have to **make a query that returns all the blog rows of a specific date and all the related translations in the same row**.

---

I have tried with

```
SELECT b.id, b.category, bt.title 
FROM blogs b 
INNER JOIN blog_translations bt ON b.id = bt.blog_id 
WHERE DATE(b.created_at) = '2010-11-12';
```

But the result is not what was expected:

[image: Bad result]

Any help please?

Thank you.

Comment: Based on my understanding, your current query IS "make a query that returns all the blog rows of a specific date and all the related translations in the same row." -- you are only getting id =1... could you elaborate what the issue is? you only want to see the record where the language is english? just guessing here

Comment: I want a table to be displayed as the third table that I have put in my question.
Sorry. I know my English is very bad.

Comment: OH okay that makes sense. thank you

Comment: What do you mean by those dots in the final result? Do you mean if there are few more languages then they should come after these columns?

Comment: Is only a example. Only need this languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/442290/54584

```
SELECT b.id, b.category, 
  max(case when bt.language = 'es' then bt.title end) title_es,
  max(case when bt.language = 'en' then bt.title end) title_en,
  max(case when bt.language = 'ca' then bt.title end) title_ca
FROM blogs b 
INNER JOIN blog_translations bt ON b.id = bt.blog_id 
WHERE DATE(b.created_at) = '2010-11-12'
GROUP BY b.id, b.category;
```